# How to prevent code from running when div is being dragged

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, wordpress-rest-api, abort

When dragging a div in muuri.js or jQuery UI the div gets a class of "dragging".
How can I stop the event listener from running createHTML(); function while being dragged and after letting go of the div? I want the click only to run the function after a fast click but not to run when holding and dragging.

```
var loadContentButton = document.getElementById("load-content-button-<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>");
var loadContentContainer = document.getElementById("content-pop-up");
var loadContentContainerWrap = document.getElementById("pop-up");

if (loadContentButton) {
  loadContentButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ourRequest.open('GET', 'http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>');
  ourRequest.onload = function() {

  if (ourRequest.status >= 200 && ourRequest.status < 400) {
     var data = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
     console.log(data);
     createHTML(data);
     loadContentContainerWrap.classList.add("active-pop-up-main");

  } else {
   console.log("We connected to the server, but it returned an error.");
  }
};

ourRequest.onerror = function() {
console.log("Connection error");
};

ourRequest.send();
  });
}

function createHTML(postsData) {
var ourHTMLString = '';
  ourHTMLString += '<h2>' + postsData.title.rendered + '</h2>';
  ourHTMLString += postsData.content.rendered;
  loadContentContainer.innerHTML = ourHTMLString;
}
```

Comment: You want to prevent the function from executing if the button is being dragged?

Comment: Yes, when letting go of the div it runs the code. I wan't to prevent that.